# how to remove deprecated code from the old django migration files

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am removing dead code in my django apps, and realized that one of the functions is being used in an old migration file. What is the correct way to remove this code from the old migration file without causing database issues?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the django `squashmigrations` command, and see if it recognises and removes the redundancy.  [More about squashing migrations in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing).